# Can I use pressure treated lumber to build a wall?

Tags: framing, construction, load-bearing

I have couple of 2X4 8' pressure treated lumbers left, Can I use them as King/Jack studs to support a 2"X 10" header in one of the load bearing wall in my basement ?

Thanks

Comment: Pressure treated means they are treated with some chemicals to prevent rottenning. It may include arsenic. Not suitable for inside house use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but there are things you need to keep in mind. Pressure treated lumber requires hot dipped galvanized nails to fasten it in place. The treatment will rust regular nails to the point over time, they are worthless. So that being said, anything else you fasten to that material needs to be hot dipped galvanized or at least rated for use in ACQ/treated lumber.

As a mention, if you used them for the king studs and not the jack studs then the drywall or doors would have regular wood to fasten to. Just be certain to use the proper nails or fasteners to set it in place. No need to take chances

Comment: If the treated wood is dry and will not be getting wet again will it still eat non acq fasteners?

Comment: There is a chance, but of the demoed material I have seen that had regular nails, they looked pretty bad. The nails were not totally shot, but where not as they should be. For structural framing, it is a no brainer to use the proper nails for that. If a door is going in an opening, it would be best to use proper nails there too. If drywall is going to cover the framing and a few screws or nails rust up because of that, it is not disastrous. If a jack stud or header fails....big problems.

Comment: Its been 6 months when i purchased them. Can i use outdoor screw ? i know its uncommon to screw it with top/bottom plate. but screw will holds very well.

Comment: Outdoor screws would be fine, as long as the packaging specifies pressure treated/acq.

Comment: Yes indeed, not a problem, screws are being used more often in remodeling for attaching framing nowadays. As long as they are rated for contact with ACQ/treated lumber